# Unable to find the development tool `cc`

Tags: nvidia, gcc

i tried to install nvidia file using this command

```
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.80.02.run
```

and got

```
ERROR: Unable to find the development tool `cc` in your path; please make sure that you have the package 'gcc' installed.  If gcc is installed on your system, then please check that `cc` is in your PATH.
```

i checked `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:opt/openmpi/bin:/usr/local:/usr/lib:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib:/usr/bin/g++:/usr/bin/gcc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a standard 20.04 system, `cc` is usually a symlink handled by the alternatives system to the GNU C compiler (`gcc`):

```
$ ls $(which cc) -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Nov 21  2018 /usr/bin/cc -> /etc/alternatives/cc

$ ls /etc/alternatives/cc -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Nov 21  2018 /etc/alternatives/cc -> /usr/bin/gcc
```

You probably don't have `build-essential` installed, and NVIDIA needs the compiler bits to actually install and handle the driver.  Run `sudo apt install build-essential` and install the GCC compiler and such via that package.  Then run the `.run` file from nVidia again.

Comment: i already used this command `sudo apt install build-essential` but error still exist

Comment: @user3188912 Run `which cc` and include the output in your comment.

Comment: i got nothing .

Comment: @user3188912 Are you **absolutely sure** that `gcc` is installed?  `which gcc` please.

Comment: i first use this command `sudo apt install build-essential` and checked and got nothing installed then i used this command `sudo apt install gcc-7 g++-7 gcc-8 g++-8 gcc-9 g++-9`

Comment: @user3188912 you *really* should not be installing the independent GCC versions yourself, and you didn't confirm that `gcc` is a binary.   I was going to assist you with establishing the `cc` symlink but can't unless you confirm that `gcc` is installed via `which gcc` so I know the default compiler on your system.  The fact you have so many `gcc` versions installed may be causing the system confusion hence things aren't present (such as `cc`)

Comment: now i removed the versions of gcc and used this command only `sudo apt install build-essential` and worked finally

Comment: @user3188912 glad to hear it!